# Class Cannot Be Resolved To A Variable

Tags: java

I am trying to cast my component to a custom Class name (OuterSpace) and it says I cannot do this.  I am doing this in a class that inherits from JFrame.

```
//Add the game to the JFrame
add(new OuterSpace());
(OuterSpace)(getComponents()[0]).start();
```

It cannot be resolved however, even to any other class name.  Here is the error-

```
OuterSpace cannot be resolved to a variable.
```

Comment: Please show a minimum working example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Please post your actual and complete error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks wrong:

```
(OuterSpace)(getComponents()[0]).start();
```

It usually is done:

```
((OuterSpace)getComponents()[0]).start();
```

---

Having said this, regardless of what is right or wrong, this code looks like a fragile and dangerous kludge. If this were my project, I'd try to hold a more secure class-specific reference to my OuterSpace field, one that would not require casting, or require that my component be in a specific component array position.

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark: I'm glad that it helps, but please see edit to answer. Your code has a dangerous code smell to me.

Comment: One more thing, where does the add method for JFrame add the component to?  Because I check the getComponents().length before and after I add the canvas to the frame, and it doesn't increase in size.

Comment: I know I should probably have made a new question, but it relates to the old one in some form.

Comment: @TheUnrealMegashark: it adds the component to the JFrame's contentPane which is held by the JRootPane. Again, your code should be thrown out. Create a variable to hold a reference to your OuterSpace instance. Don't use kludgy code like this code.